# How do I measure the correlation between these two events?

Tags: bayesian

I'm trying to measure the influence of one event over the other. Say we have two articles $A$ and $B$. We have knowledge about the users reading these two articles, so I'm trying to measure $P(B|A)$ here.

Intuitively, I feel that the larger $P(B|A)$ is, the more influence the event "one has read article $A$" will influence "one will read article $B$". But again $B$ might be a very popular article s.t. $P(B)$ is almost close to 1. So here $P(B)$ is almost equal to $P(B|A)$.

I think $P(B|A) - P(B)$ might be something I could possibly use here but I don't know whether it makes any sense mathematically. How should I try to measure these influences better?

Comment: What do you mean by "influences??

Comment: @PeterFlom I'm not sure how I should interpret this statistically but in layman's term I think it means the two events A and B do not occur together just by chance.

Answer (score 1):

You usually want to consider the ratio between pairs of probabilities $P(B\vert A)/P(B)$ instead of the differences.

More generally, and formally, you want to consider the relative entropy ([Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence))

$$
 H =  \sum_b P(b) \ln \frac{ p(b) }{ p(b | A ) }  
$$

which is $0$ for $p(b) = p(b \vert A)$, i.e. the outcome on $B$ is independent of $A$ having occurred, and grows as the conditional distribution becomes "more different" from the prior.